# Adding standard field using API

Tags: api

I want to add a standard field on contact object page layout using API . How can I do that, just a high level solution will help to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really just two steps. First, query the layout using readMetadata from the metadata API, modify the layout in memory, then call the updateMetadata function to modify the layout on the server. Details for how to do this are in the metadata API documentation. The user attempting the change must have customize application, or the call will fail.